# how to import (.dmp) database from oracle 10g to phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, oracle, phpmyadmin

I have receive database backup from my friends that using oracle (.dmp) and now I want to import the database into phpmyadmin, did someone know how to import them ?

Comment: Oracle RDBMS dump files from export/expdp are in a proprietary format. MySQL is a completely separate database product (that happens to now be owned by the same company) and cannot do anything with a .dmp. You can only import into another Oracle database.

Comment: @AlexPoole I think you should make this an answer, as it's the best response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle RDBMS dump files from export/expdp are in a proprietary format. MySQL is a completely separate database product (that happens to now be owned by the same company) and cannot do anything with a .dmp. You can only import into another Oracle database.